# How to Rediscover a Networked Computer

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have two computers on my LAN and they both could see each other at one time. At that time, I was running two ethernet cables from two ports on my workstation to my router. This turned out to be a mistake as it caused BSOD's and it took me about four months to figure out it was the problem. At this point, the laptop can see the workstation and I can move files to and from it. The workstation can't see the laptop except as a media device. I'm thinking if I can delete the laptop from the workstation's 'view' and let it rediscover it, it would correct the problem. How can I do this? Both systems are running Windows 7 with the workstation being 64 bit. The laptop connection is wireless.

Comment: Update: the laptop appeared on the work station's network as a computer for a while, but has disappeared again. It's still there as a media device. Doesn't answer my question, however.